# jquery trim value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript:

```
var value = '19-JUL-10 04.36.38.643000 PM-->19-JUL-10 05.06.33.962000 PM'
```

How can I use jQuery to trim it to become `'19-JUL-10 04.36.38 PM-->19-JUL-10 05.06.33 PM'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for jQuery, plain ol' JavaScript will do. Use a regular expression with the [*replace()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```
var value = '19-JUL-10 04.36.38.643000 PM-->19-JUL-10 05.06.33.962000 PM';
alert(value.replace(/\.\d{6}/g, ""));
//-> "19-JUL-10 04.36.38 PM-->19-JUL-10 05.06.33 PM"
```

The regular expression, `/\.\d{6}/g`, looks for a `.` immediately followed by and including 6 consecutive digits (`\d{6}`).   The global switch (`/g`) is applied to make it replace all (both) occurrences.

Comment: i was going to suggest substr, but this is far more elegant